# Is this question appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm on two student project teams that are pretty much desperate for programmers. We recruit every semester, but get mostly mechanical and electrical engineers to apply (the projects are about 33/33/33 mech/ece/cs). Would a (more detailed) question asking for advice on how to get more programmers to apply be off-topic for SO? If so, where else can I ask?

Answer (score 2):

It is likely to be off-topic because it's about your *particular* recruiting problem. If you were to ask a *generalized* recruiting question, it would have about 30% chance of surviving.

However, there are a huge amount of general career/recruiting questions on Stack Overflow already. Browse through them, you may get very helpful insight there.